# Heroku not working for Node.js file with python scripts

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, web-applications

I made a website in node.js and I have used child process to run python scripts and use their results in my website. But when I host my application on heroku, heroku is unable to run the python scripts.

I have noticed that heroku was able to run python scripts which only had inbuilt python packages like sys, json but it was failing for scripts which were using external packages like requests, beautifulsoup.

Attempt-1
I made a requirements.txt file inside the project folder and pushed my code to heroku again. But it was still not working. I noticed that heroku uses the requirements.txt file only for python based web applications but not for node.js applications.

Attempt-2
I made a python virtual env inside the project folder and imported the required python packages into the venv. I then removed gitignore from the venv and pushed the whole venv folder to heroku. It still didn't work.

Please let me know if anyone came across a way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Have a requirements.txt file in your project folder.

After you create a heroku app using "heroku create", heroku will identify your app as python based and will not download any of the node dependencies.

Now, go to your heroku profile and go to your app's settings. There is an option named "Add Buildpack" in there. Click on that and add node.js as one of the buildpacks.

Go back to your project and push it to heroku. This time heroku will identify your app as both python and node.js based and will download all the required files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format) to specify a command to install the python dependencies then start the server.

Procfile:

```
web: pip install -r requirements.txt && npm start
```

Place `Procfile` in your project's root directory and deploy to heroku.

Comment: It did not work for me. But adding python as a buildpack in heroku's settings did the job.